# Can not create ionic 2 app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am following the ionic installation guide, but when I want to create app it give me error.

The command I enter is:

```
ionic start cutePuppyPics --v2
```

The error it gives is:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\v\\nodev7.0.0\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.9.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.9.3 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\nodeProjects\ionic\cutePuppyPics\npm-debug.log
Error with start undefined
Error Initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
Caught exception:
 undefined

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
```

Comment: Can you please add the version of `node` and `npm` that you're using? To do so, just run `node -v` and `npm --version`.

Comment: I am using node version v7.0.0 and npm v3.10.6

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Node `v7.0.0` causes this problem. Instead of nodejs `v7.0.0` use nodejs `v6.9.1` or install LTS version of node from https://nodejs.org/en/download

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use --v2 when creating your project. Just type

```
ionic start cutePuppyPics blank
```

Answer (score 0):

`--v2` is not working with latest ionic. you can use

```
ionic start cutePuppyPics ionic-angular  (for ionic 2.x)
ionic start cutePuppyPics ionic1 (ionic 1.x)
```